# Limiting internet access on certain PC's

Tags: router

I have a Draytek Vigor 2950 router. I want to restrict access to the internet to certain times for the kids PC's such as only 16:00 to 20:00, but have full access at all times for mine and the wifes. Can this be done if so how?

Thanks

Daedalus

Comment: You can find the user manual here: http://www.draytek.co.uk/support/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I do already have the manual. The trouble for me is it is written in "IP Speak" which I have no idea about, it really is not user friendly. I was hoping someone may have it in sensible English.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do:

1) first, make sure that your pcs are always assigned the same IP address.

2) Implement a no-access policy.

1a) Go to page 50 of your manual, you will find a copy of a Web page of your router. Now open the Web page of your router. You do this by typing either 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.254 in your browser's address bar. Now click on LAN -> Bind IP to MAC. You will knwo that you are on the right page if page 50 of your manual is what you see on your screen.

Write down the IP addresses you see under the Heading "ARP Table", "IP Address". Check the "Enable" dotted circle. Click OK.

1b) Now, with your list of IP addresses, check which one belongs to the pcs you want to allow to navigate at all times, perhaps yours and your wifes, but maybe also your smartphones. You can check their IP addresses as follows: if you have a Windows machine, click on Run -> terminal, now give the command ipconfig. Within the output, you will find one of the IP addresses you jotted down earlier. Check that you want to save it. If you have a Mac, open a Terminal, and give the command ifconfig (notice the small difference between the two commands). Again, search for one of the IP addresses you previously jotted down.

2) Go to page 75 of the manual. You will see there a copy of the Web page of your router. To access that page, click on CSM -> URL Content Filter. You will know you are on the right page if page 75 of the manual is what you see on the screen.

Now Check: Enable URL Access Control, Enable URL Access Log, White List, the ACT square next to 1, an add a * (star) as a keyword. Then check Enable Restrict Web Feature, and all of the boxes from Java to Proxy.

Check Enable Excepting Subnets, check the Act box and insert the IP addresses that you have determined at step 1b, i.e. your pc's IP address, your wife's, and what not. Fill in as many lines as there are pcs to whom you do NOT want to apply access restrictions, all indicated by the appropriate IP.

Lastly, choose your Time schedule. notice that, sine we have chosen as an action to block all access to the Internet, the time to insert in the boxes is the time range where you want to deny your kids access to the Internet.

Review what you have just done, check that this is what you really want, breathe deeply, check ok, you are done. Cheers.